Concatenating 2 environmental variables in a ksh script
I have a storage.src file with the following 2 environmental variables exported
export FIRST="HelloHelloHello"
export SECOND="World"

I have a .sh file as follows
#!/bin/ksh

. /absolute/path/to/storage.src

CONCAT_STRING="${FIRST}${SECOND}"
echo "$FIRST"
echo "$SECOND"
echo "$CONCAT_STRING"

I get the following output
HelloHelloHello
World
WorldHelloHello

CONCAT_STRING should output HelloHelloHelloWorld. But it looks like World is overwriting the FIRST variable. Any idea as to why?

Likely your storage.src file has Windows style (CRLF) line endings

... see similar Weird behaviour of string concatenation in Bash

Yes, the FIRST variable has a  hidden CR in it, so you''re actually getting HelloHelloHello^MWorld.  You can see this if you pass the echo output through od; eg echo "$CONCAT_STRING | od -cx and you'll see the \r in the middle
